# parse_variables doesn't parse pairs variables

Tags: php, expressionengine

Expression Engine function `parse_variables` doesn't parse pairs variables.
Php code

```
    myd($tagdata);
    myd($replace_array);
    return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, array($replace_array));
```

output

```
{faq_row} {faqtitle}
{faqbody} {faq_row}

Array
(
    [faq_row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [faqtitle] => lkjlkjklj
                    [faqbody] => lkjlkjlkjklj

                )

        )

)

{faq_row} {faqtitle}
{faqbody} {faq_row}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have missed close tag char '/'.